# Is it possible to omit some objects in a scene from being affected by the environment texture lighting?

Tags: lighting

I have a scene setup with some objects which i want to be affected by the environment texture i have created and some which i dont (they are darker areas and are being lit up too much) - Is it possible to omit some objects in a scene from being affected by the environment texture lighting?

Comment: I guess you need to use the Compositor

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to render it all at once in Cycles. You can use 2 different View Layers with collections as masks to render twice and composite them in the compositor.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: great thats a good fix, thanks very much for that. shame theres no way to have more control over the lighting prior to render...